# HTTP server through NAT (without access to the router config) with a fixed domain name

Tags: networking, nat, dynamic-dns, noip

I need my client to connect to my http server from outside and I don't have access to the router settings, we are trough NAT.

Let's say the domain is going to be example.com

My client must change his windows host file to point example.com to my public IP.

However as I am trough NAT it wont reach me.

Is there any service like Dyn or No-ip that can act as public IP (instead of hostname) and then the service reach my machine?

Then my client can change his host with that public IP.

Comment: What you need is a tunnel. I saw another question recently where somebody mentioned a commercial solution though I would just set up a VPN.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Maybe that's the solution but that would be way too complicated for my client :( Also any software like Hamachi is not an option because he will need to install software and register. As a condition windows hosts it the only thing my client should "touch".

Comment: If you can't install or configure any software, this is going to be very hard.

Comment: *You* can operate the tunnel. Tunnel from you to a VPN provide that gives you a unique IP and allows forwarding, then get the client to hit that IP instead of yours.

Comment: Thanks @Linef4ult . I finally scalated the problem and they forwarded the ports. So I am OK now, however I leave the question open if someone can tell any VPN provider that can do that.